# I am using a firebase android codelab to create an app like friendlychat and for some reason it doesn't let me build the apk. How do I resolve this?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using a firebase android codelab to create an app like friendlychat and for some reason it doesn't let me build the apk. How do I resolve this?

[image]

These are the errors said.

[image]

[image]

Thankyou

Comment: please follow the docs and the error itself. Both specify that you need the google services.json file which you can get from firebase console

Answer (score 0):

You need to click here to generate that missing json config file.

[image: steps to generate json config]